# aws cloud front ssl with simple wordpress site

Tags: cloud

[Route53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EtDD.png)[CDN6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDv3P.png)[CDN5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEglg.png)[CDN4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATdGw.png)[CDN3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s4Lh.png)[CDN2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WebzD.png)[CDN1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O8id.png)i have ec2(ubuntu1804-lamp) install with wordpress, and pointed to mydomain.com, its works fine without ssl,now i want to put this ec2 instance behind cloudfront with custom ssl (AWS ACM) mydomain.com. i have create cloud front with origin awscdn.mydomain.com, origin protocol policy = HTTP only, behaviours settings is default(*), viewer protocol policy = HTTP and HTTPS, Forward query strings = yes. In My Route53, i pointed awscdn.mydomain.com (A) record to ec2 ip address, and mydomain.com is pointed (A-Alias) to CloudFront domain(abcxyz.cloudfront.net).
When i request mydomain.com is return in http, but when i manually request https mydomain.com its return with blocked image (css,js). web server is apache2 running on ec2 instance....how to redirect my ec2 to http to https ?

Possible Help, appreciate....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cloudfront has an option to allow redirect to HTTPS when a request is sent through under behaviors

Comment: Thanks a lot....for you answer....i did allow redirect to HTTPS and got below error while loading my wordpress page......

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.2.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
f @ (index):13
8Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=5.2.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Comment: Do you have a SSL cert on the EC2 instance as well ?

Comment: It seems like the EC2 instance is serving HTTP content and that is why you are getting that error

Comment: No, i do not have any kind of SSL install on apache web server (ec2)

Comment: yes my ec2 webserver is serving traffic on http port 80, thats why in cloudfront origin protocol policy  "HTTP only" is selected. if i select HTTPS only i get bad request error, if i selecy "Match Viewer" policy, page is being server good in HTTP but if i add HTTPS its throw same error (mixed content) as i mentioned above.

Comment: So you are pointing to your EC2 then re-directing traffic to your CloudFront ? If this is what is happening, it is sending http traffic because their is no CERT on the EC2 instance that is sending it to CloudFront if I understand what you are saying.

Comment: when request comes to my naked domain.com, it should be served by cloudfront first as per caching TTL, if TTL expires CDN will contact origin server (my ec2) and request would served. it works http(80) but gives mixed content error in in https(443), how could i resolved this issue ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the errors you are getting in the inspect > console of the console?

Comment: i am new at stackoverflow, could you help me out in order to share screenshot with you ?...thanks a lot

Comment: Use a screen capture software, also just update/edit your answer to upload something new to it

Comment: How could i add my screenshot here in comment ?

Comment: i added my all settings screenshot in my question, could you see it ?

Comment: No I dont see them at all

Comment: then how could i share it with you ?